# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many relationship basic understanding fails - no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two classes, `ProjectTypes`, and `RiskTypes`, both are many to many, so both have a has_and_belongs_to relationship on the model.

When I run `rails c` I can do the following:

```
r1 = RiskType.last
```

which returns the last risk type

```
#<RiskType:0x00007f15e0a20d58
id: 5,
Rtype_name: "test type",
```

and the same for project type

```
p2 = ProjectType.last
```

and the relationship works as when I run

```
r1.project_types
```

I get the project type I set in my seed, but now if I want to change that so that r1 is now related to p2 I get an error.

```
r1.project_types = p2
```

the error is:

```
/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activemodel-6.1.4.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:469:in `method_missing': undefined method `each' for #<ProjectType id: 2, Ptype_name: "EDD", created_at: "2022-09-27 08:17:58.382009000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-09-27 08:17:58.382009000 +0000"> (NoMethodError)
```

This is obviously some basic understanding of relationships I don't understand yet, any help much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since project_types is an array, you have to assign it as follows:

```
r1.project_types = [p2]
```

Comment: Warning: You may end up removing project types if there are any. Prefer `r1.project_types << p2`

Comment: You're right, but he wanted to `change that so that r1 is now related to p2`